# How Can I intercept high level GDI draw commands?

Tags: streaming, drawing, gdi, internals

I'm trying to make a application that allows remote access to other applications (running on different machines). The idea is to make give users transparent accesso to certain applications, I've basically two options:

- Application Streaming
- Intercepting draw command and reproduce them in the client

(of course, the input is redirected from the client to the server)

I've a working version with application streaming, but I don't have a clue of how to do it through hooking in the Win API...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds a lot like a Windows metafile. The metafile captures all GDI drawing commands to a file; that file can then be passed to a remote PC and rendered there.

See [CreateEnhMetaFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183498(VS.85).aspx) for starters. This returns a handle to a device context, which you draw to instead of drawing to the normal screen device context.